# Value not received in Another Fragment using Bundle

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-volley

I am using `Volley` library to fetch JSON data.In my first `Fragment` I am receiving some value which I need to send in second `Fragment`. I am using `Bundles` to pass data between `Fragments`.
This is my JSON request.

```
private void getCount() {
        String url="http://192.168.1.106:9500/api/restqueue/";
        String json_req = "json_req";
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response.toString());
                            count=object.getString("name");

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }

                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                String credentials = name+":"+pass;
                String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                headers.put("Content-type", "application/json");
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                return headers;
            }
        };

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, json_req);
    }
```

This is Code in `MainAtivity` to sand data from FragmentOne

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("totcount",count);
                ChooseTab choose=new ChooseTab();
                choose.setArguments(bundle);
```

This is code to get data from `Bundle` in FragmentTwo

```
Bundle bundle=this.getArguments();
            count=bundle.getString("totcount","empty");
```

This is code for adding data in Bundle

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose,container,false);
        test=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.test);
        queue=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.queue);
        waiter=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.waiter);
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.choose);
        prefs=getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        name=prefs.getString("name","empty");
        pass=prefs.getString("pass","empty");
        getCount();

        fm=getFragmentManager();
        name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tag="";
                tx=fm.beginTransaction();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("totcount",count);
                ChooseTab choose=new ChooseTab();
                choose.setArguments(bundle);
                tx.replace(R.id.frame,choose,tag);
                tx.addToBackStack(tag);
                tx.commit();
            }
        });
        fullname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tagg="";
                tx=fm.beginTransaction();
                tx.replace(R.id.frame,new Waiter());
                tx.addToBackStack(tagg);
                tx.commit();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

I am getting error

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.BaseBundle.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: share your whole code for adding bundle in your `FragmentOne`

Comment: FragmentTwo is really an instance of ChooseTab?

Comment: Have your checked null of "count" in your main activity yet ?

Comment: @Satyam, what is `fm`?

Comment: fragment manager instance buddy\

Comment: Its a FragmentManager

Comment: please show your code where you get data in first fragment

Comment: I am getting data in My FirstFragment in getCount() method

Comment: for getting Bundle value in Fragment Two, are you putting inside onActivityCreated()

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment 2,
OnCreateView method, try using getArguements().getString("KEY", "DEFAULT_VALUE") directly, instead of creating a bundle. This might solve. or to be more precise,

```
tx=fm.beginTransaction();
```

use that line after

```
choose.setArguments(bundle);
```

Comment: It is saying InCompatible types

Comment: @Satyam Gobdhalw, please check value of the variable you are passing is not null..